# GCC fatal error no input files in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

This portion of the code works. I start by stating what compiler I'm going to use and some basic logic for my project (I'm trying to create a basic raspberry pi os). Most of what I have done is from a guide I found online https://jsandler18.github.io/tutorial/dev-env.html I don't mind starting again but would like to know what is going on.

```
    CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc

    ifeq ($(RASPI_MODEL),1)
         CPU = arm1176jzf-s
         DIRECTIVES = -D MODEL_1
    else
         CPU = cortex-a7
    endif

    CFLAGS= -mcpu=$(CPU) -fpic -ffreestanding $(DIRECTIVES)
    CSRCFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
    LFLAGS= -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib

    KER_SRC = ../src/kernel
    KER_HEAD = ../include
    COMMON_SRC = ../src/common
    OBJ_DIR = objects
    KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.c)
    COMMONSOURCES = $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC)/*.c)
    ASMSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.S)
    OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCES))
    OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(COMMONSOURCES))
    OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.S, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
    HEADERS = $(wildcard $(KER_HEAD)/*.h)

    IMG_NAME=kernel.img
```

GCC error stating no input files on this portion of code. If I remove the -o and move the -T it doesn't give me an error, but it still doesn't work. I'm guessing it has something to do with $(OBJECTS) or the order of my flags.

```
     build: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
          echo $(OBJECTS)
          $(CC) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
```

This part is supposed to create a new directory and create a easy to understand structure. No matter what I try to modify it doesn't work. I suspect the $(@D) to be the culprit, I found very little to none documentation of this in makefiles and don't understand it.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.c
     mkdir -p $(@D)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)
```

The same applies here instead of creating a structure it does nothing, absolutely nothing.

```
 $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.S
      mkdir -p $(@D)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -c $< -o $@

 $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c
      mkdir -p $(@D)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)
```

This doesn't remove anything, no matter what I try. For this part I'm clueless as to what the problem could be.

```
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm $(IMG_NAME)
```

This part is working, I'm shure if I run my build it will execute this command and do its job.

```
run: build
    qemu-system-arm -m 1024 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.img
```

When trying to run this makefile I used:

```
make build
```

This outputs the following:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -T linker.ld -o kernel.img -ffreestanding -O2 - 
nostdlib   
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: build] Error 1
```

When running

```
ls ../src
```

The terminal outputs

```
ls: cannot access '../src': No such file or directory
```

When running 'dir' in the terminal the following apears:

```
boot.o  boot.S  cpp_make.cpp  gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major  kernel.c  kernel.img  linker.ld  Makefile  myos.elf  rasemu  src
```

Comment: To get assistance please show (a) the make command you invoked, (b) the command line make ran that failed, and (c) the error messages you got (if there are lots of them please show the _first_ messages (and possibly the last ones as well: if you want to elide messages elide the middle ones especially if they're more of the same).  Please use cut and paste with appropriate formatting, rather than paraphrasing parts of error messages.

Comment: First I ran "make build" then "make run". Line 34 and "arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: build] Error 1

Comment: That's not what we need.  First, please edit your question rather than adding comments: comments cannot be formatted properly.  Second you showed (a) and (c) but not (b): what is the command line that make invoked?  If you just cut and paste the appropriate output from your terminal into your question, and add formatting so it's a non-formatted block, that will help.  Basically this error means that the compiler invocation is wrong but you don't show us the compiler invocation so it's not clear _how_ it's wrong.

Comment: My first guess would be the sources are not found by the wildcard command, so KERSOURCE etc are empty. You sure the sources are in `../src` relative to where you invoke the makefile? What does `ls ../src` show? As a side note, question title should probably be more specific, including part of the error message like "fatal error: no input files". Otherwise it matches like every makefile question anyone had ever. Also, that's a gcc message, not a make message.